# Is it fair to use painting software for tetris puzzles?

Tags: the-witness

As the title says I am curious if it's fair to do this. Some of the tetris puzzles are just too hard to solve them mentally for me, so I came up to that kind of aids.

[image]

On the one hand I feel like cheating or reading a solution, on the other hand I still need to use my mind for solving.

Comment: What you do is up to you; we can't really answer this, as its completely subjective

Comment: You can solve the puzzles with whatever method you like. Till you solve them by your-self, it's still fair.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a singleplayer game, as with all single player games only you can answer this question. If you want to do it then do it, otherwise don't.

It's your game to play with how you want to. If using photoshop is how you want to do it then do it that way. Are you looking for more of a challenge or do you want to just complete the game?

Many people play games with self imposed rules because that's how they want to play the game for whatever reason. Skyrim is an example of this, some people choose to not do any 'evil' deeds such as looting or stealing, or some choose to not fast travel or whatever. While on the other side of things some people will use commands or mods to make themselves stronger, faster or whatever.

Just do whatever you find most enjoyable.